# Meaning of "shrift"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

The other day I ran into "shrift". Google default said it meant "to shrink". All dictionary links said "confession in a church". In context this hardly poses a problem, but what would be the default you'd think of when hearing this word without context?

Comment: What do you mean by "google default"? Shrift is a form of shrive. It usually appears in the fixed phrase "short shrift", q.v.

Comment: Seconding @Jack that "short shrift" is the *only* place I've heard the word.

Comment: If a Catholic has committed sins which have not yet been confessed and absolved, they (and the sinner) are said to be _unshriven_. To die unshriven was, and is, a disaster for a Catholic.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty: Google gives an automatic translation (maybe since I'm a German) when I enter ' "shrift" english' as a search, and it gives "schrumpfen". But (can you repeat the effect?) why is the translation completely incorrect? "Shrive" gives the same BTW!

Comment: @HaukeReddmann The google search bar doesn't do that here in the US. At wordreference. com I see that one sense of "schrumpfen" is "shrivel" in English, which is only one letter away from shrive in spelling (though far away in meaning)..

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty: Exactly! I realized that today myself (and if I had also thought about shrift-shrive, gift-give, drift-drive, lift-live...OK, so much for making analogies in a second language :-)...I could have understood it much earlier...)

Comment: shrift is to shrive as gift is to give as rift is to rive as theft is to thieve as weft is to weave (but not as lift is to live)

Comment: 50 yr old American have lived east coast, midwest, south, traveled, fairly well read, never heard this before.

Comment: @hobbs: You forgot cleave-cleft? (Once I know the rules, I can happily chime in...) Or is this better filed with leave-left? (Can be more than one word type...)

Comment: Postshrift. (Aargh! Not the pitchfork! :-) This happens to me all the time, I've never seen the word before and days later it jumps at me (of course you can blame it on selective bias). Usually "days" rather really means at most a week, not two months, but anyway, today I read "make short shrift" in a SCIENCE issue of 2019.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Apart from the idiom *give somebody/something short shrift* (=give it no attention or consderation) the word is obsolete unless you are talking about historical Christanity, and most English speakers will have no idea at all what it means. (Not hyperbole: I don't mean that they won't know exactly what it means: I think few will even recognise it as connected with the Church).

Comment: One thing I find interesting here, I agree about not knowing "shrift" but I did know "shriven" (basically that someone has had their sins forgiven) and it does make sense there is a connection between the two.

Comment: Another fossilised remnant is _Shrove_, in "Shrove Tuesday". Completely opaque to most current English speakers.

Comment: I would say that my sense of “short shrift” isn’t *no* attention or consideration, but *little, and certainly less than deserved*. It has a certain sense that this is perhaps an even greater indignity, because it wasn’t merely missed or forgotten, but considered and dismissed out of hand, possibly paying only lip service to the idea that a matter was given its due.

Comment: @Colin Fine: Not just opaque in the meaning of shrove, but most US speakers who don't belong to the particular sect(s) would have little if any idea what or when "Shrove Tuesday" actually is.

Comment: @jamesqf even in England, most people normally call it Pancake Day instead and, whilst I expect most have heard of Shrove Tuesday, I suspect many don't realise that it and Pancake Day are the same day, or have any idea what the name means

Comment: @Tristan: Americans call it Mardi Gras, I think.

Comment: @TonyK yep! Mardi Gras, aka Fat Tuesday, aka Shrove Tuesday, aka Pancake Day. Basically - eat lots of fatty rich foods before Ash Wednesday marks the beginning of Lent and you give all that stuff up for 40 days

Comment: I was brought up in the wrong sort of Christianity but am still familiar with "shriven" in the sense of absolution and its connection to "shrove", i.e. I'm one of the few who would recognise it a church-related but be hazy on the details.  However the link to "shrift" isn't instant. While the pattern is similar to others (e.g. "gift" & "given"), "shrift" and "shriven" are both so rare as to escape consideration.   [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-german/shrift) is helpful searching for *shrift German*

Comment: @Tristan: I'd never heard of Pancake Day until just now.  And while I'd heard of Shrove Tuesday before, I'd never known when or why, or that it was related to Mardi Gras.  Which is very much a regional thing in the US: outside of New Orleans & adjacent areas, it really isn't generally celebrated.

Comment: The idiom was originally of a priest rushing his parishioners through their confessions, which you *really* aren't supposed to do since they believe(d?) it's a critical act that, if not done correctly, leaves your soul in peril of hell should you die. Thus "short shrift" was, in its original form, not just dismissively ignoring somebody's needs, but puts them in grave danger.

Comment: I have been a Christian since the age of 7, having grown up in a Christian family, and I literally do not recognize the words "shrift" or "shriven" at all.

Answer (score 13):

The (more or less) modern idiom: "To give someone or something short shrift."

Someone or something asks you for consideration, and you *mostly* dismiss them. You don't entirely dismiss them, but you decline to give them your full attention and/or the time required for true engagement.

The historical background would be a priest's perfunctory performance of the sacrament of confession: to only  give the person limited time and attention.

Answer (score 2):

The word shrift is an archaic noun referring to the confession or absolution of sins. These days, "shrift" is rarely encountered on its own, but it does keep frequent company with "short" in the phrase "short shrift.It is a remission of sins pronounced by a priest in the sacrament of reconciliation.

Comment: Shrift is *never* used on its own today, it's not a word.

Answer (score 0):

In English, there are a number of "words" which only occur in a specific, "idiomatic" usage as part of a longer phrase.

The actual original meaning of the "word" is totally lost, and the word itself is never used.

"Short-shrift" is such a phrase.

"Shrift" is not a word.

(In any meaningful sense of "not a word".  Maybe it was a word 500 years ago, whatever.  Lots of words were words 500 years ago, and are now not words. It's not a word.  You can't use it.)

Note that indeed furthermore, the pharse "short-shrift" as such, is never used in any way.  The longer phrase "... gave him short-shrift" or "to give short-shrift" is the only usage.

(It just means to "blow them off", to use a modern phrase; to dismiss them.)

Comment: "Not a word" is quite different from "An archaic word that no-one uses these days." [Secability](http://phrontistery.info/clw4.html) is a [lost word](http://phrontistery.info/clwdef.html), but it's still a word. wofkghdefklp is not an English word. And yes, this entire comment was written for the sole purpose of linking to [The Phrontistery](http://phrontistery.info/index.html) because it's an awesome site everyone interested in English words should look at :) (But also, 'shrift' is still a word even if anyone hardly ever uses it).

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree, but that's completely OK.  Shrift is not a word because (among other reasons) you can not use it today: it has no meaning.  "You can not use it", hence, not a word.  Setting that aside the point of the answer is to clearly explain to OP that in English, there's a few "words that appear only in an idiomatic phrase and otherwise do not exist".  Nobody else explained that (which is a poor show on an ELL site) other than mentioning that, the central point of this page, in passing.

Comment: Your idea of what constitutes a word is odd. I can absolutely use "gave it short shrift" today and be understood. What do you call "shrift" in that phrase if not a word? How many people of limited vocabulary have to complain before something loses its "wordhood" (wordness?)? What do you call all those groups of letters like 'barque' and 'owest' in Shakespeare's plays?

Comment: cheers Colleen - the word, on its own, can not be used.

Comment: regarding people of limited vocabulary, I never talk to them and suggest you don't :) :)

Comment: the two words you mention from 1500s are not words.  (they once were, much like shrift)

Comment: I don’t mind limited vocabularies if they have words in them I don’t have in my own ;) I enjoy “unwords” I guess.

Comment: the moving finger writes, and having writ, moves on ...

Comment: Not my language, so can't discuss, but: Germans know this phenomenon too. "Mit Fug und Recht" ("fully justified") is an ancient standing phrase and the only legit way to use "Fug".

Comment: that is awesome @HaukeReddmann , didn't know that one.  well, "shrift" is exactly like "fug".   i did live in Berlin for some years but, sadly *meine deutsche ist sehr rustig* !  :O  mfg !

Comment: @Fattie: It shows, you sound like a Hollywood German (probably intentional) :P If your German is "rostig", that's too bad, but if it's "rüstig", you can be proud! (Translation: "Rusty" vs. "agile", the latter only used if talking about a stone-old citizen. Also, for safety and German learners, the grammar is "Mein Deutsch...")

Comment: Ohh!  I'm so sorry - I did indeed mean "rusty"!  (It occurs to me, that's quite interesting: I only learned to hear and speak German entirely by ear and mouth: I never wrote, typed or read one word.  So, I better take extra care when typing.)  (Darn, now I want to be there ..... for the food!  Ayyyy!)